# What's the ideal relationship between line-height, font-size, and paragraph margin?

Tags: html, typography, css

For a long time I've noticed that adjusting `line-height` and adding some extra space between paragraphs both relative to the chosen `font-size` can make a huge impact on the readability of Web site content, but so far I have always selected ad-hoc values for these attributes.

Are there any recommendations in typography, publishing, or psychology literature for how to adjust values for these properties relative to each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't post a detailed answer, I'm afraid, but I'd suggest that you read [Tim Brown](http://www.alistapart.com/authors/b/timbrown)'s article '[More Meaningful Typography](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/more-meaningful-typography/)', at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/), for guidance.

In essence, it seems that the width ('measure') of a block of text should be around 50-60 characters, the `line-height` set at `1.5` (without a unit, which will be 1.5 times the `font-size`, regardless of the units used to set the `font-size`).

Characters themselves seem to be set around the 16px mark, but Tim suggests using a scale, such as that represented by the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) to define the relative font-sizing of headings, body text, captions and so forth.

Answer (score 8):

A deep and mathematical answer to your question can be found at "Secret Symphony: The Ultimate Guide to Readable Web Typography":  http://www.pearsonified.com/2011/12/golden-ratio-typography.php

The article takes into account three dimensions: line height, font height adn page width (well, text width) and luckily they also provide a useful calculator: Golden Ratio Typography Calculator (http://www.pearsonified.com/typography/)