# CSS calc for line-height base on viewport width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following different trails about typography for the web I bumped into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720992/325868). Doing my own math I now want to set the `line-height` based on the width. For my use case the `width` is more or less identical with the `viewport.width`.

So, my question is how to set `line-height` dynamically based on the viewports width? Basically my viewport width is minimum `300px` width and a maximum to `850px`. Basically I want to set the `line-height` something like:

```
(current viewport.width)/300*(base-factor [=1.4])
```

Is it best to approach it with jquery? Or can it be done with CSS-calc()? And how to recognize resizing (either desktop or mobile: portrait/landscape)?

Comment: `calc(100vw / (300*1.4))` ?

Comment: Yeah, thx this works. Except the `tiny` detail that the results is in unit `px`, i.e. I need to mulitply the font-size - which I know :-)

Comment: you can consider the font-size as uniteless. So if your font-size is `15px` simply multiply by `15`

Comment: Yeah, this I figured out as well ;-)